# Why its not working?

Tags: c#, binary-data

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());

int n = br.ReadInt32();
bw.Write(n);
```

always getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream.
at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer (Int32 numBytes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt32 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Program.Main () [0x00025] in /home/skydos/ACM/Csharp/Csharp/Main.cs:24
```

Is there any way to make reading data in C# faster from Console?

Comment: add cosole.readline to your code before opening binary writer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you writing anything to the standard input of your program? The error says there's no data available, quite simple.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it block until data is available?

Comment: I cannot write there anything... 'cause always I get this error before I can write anything there...

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in the MSDN documentation on how to go about dealing with System.IO stuff.  Maybe this link will get you started?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.IO.BINARYREADER);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

If speed is your main concern, perhaps this article at Code Project will give you some ideas:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fastbinaryfileinput.aspx